# Instantiated from here

Tags: c++, templates, avl-tree

I have a problem with "instantied from here".

```
template <typename E>
class tree
{
public:
    tree(){root=0;}
    void addAVL( const E &data) throw(bad_alloc);
private:
    class Node
    {
    public:

        E data;             
        Noeud * left;       
        Noeud * right;      
        int high;       
        std::string adHier; 

        Noeud( const E&d ): data( d right( 0 ),left( 0 ),high(0), adHier("") { }
    };
    Node * root;
};

#include "AVL.inl"

/*-------------------------
*in my inl
*/
template <typename E>
void tree<E>::addAVL( const E &data) throw(bad_alloc)
{
    // if the trre is empty
    if ( root == 0 )
    {
        root = new Node(data);  // HERE my error when in a cpp I call addAVL
    }
}
```

My error is:

```
../AVL.inl:98:   instantiated from ‘void AVL_Lab10::tree<E>::addAVL(const E&) [with E = int]’
../TestingAVL.cpp:30:   instantiated from here
```

Comment: Please reformat your question.

Comment: Roots - you can format code by indenting it 4 spaces.  The easiest way to do it is to highlight your code section and click the `{}` button in the editor.

Comment: The actual error message is probably exactly the line *after* the 'instantiated from here' line in the compiler output...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Noeud * left;
Noeud * right;
Noeud( const E&d ): ...
```

I guess that should be `Node` not `Noeud`? Does it fix your errors if you correct those typos?

Comment: That aside, Node is also a private inner class.

Comment: @phooji: Nothing wrong with that, as it's a privat inner class of `tree`, which should be the only class using it.

Comment: Ah I scrolled down to see the instantiation is a tree member :) Still wouldn't be my choice for a design though -- hard(er) to adjust allocation later on this way.

Comment: @phooji: I'm curious; what do you mean by "hard(er) to adjust allocation"? The only difference between a nested class and a regular one is visibility. Did you mean the ability to specify some kind of allocator policy for `tree`, like in STL containers?

Comment: @Emile Cormier: That is what I was referring to; it also applies to homebrewn datastructures if you want to switch to a pool allocator later on.

Answer (score 0):

finaly I not found the prob, but i can build... my teach say me that he have the samme prob with gcc compilator in eclipse. It's very curious because each time i add some code in my .inl and i save. The error icon display ....

Thank you for your help ! :D